# Is there a way to get a timestamp of a keystroke in C#?

Tags: c#, datetime, stopwatch, console.readkey

I'm trying to make a simple stopwatch for a C# class I'm taking. I've googled around all afternoon and found a lot of info that I either don't understand or doesn't quite deal with the problem I'm having.

As I'm currently learning about classes, methods, fields and properties, I'm trying to design my stopwatch like this:
[image: Stopwatch concept design]

I don't think it needs to be super precise. I'm trying to get a DateTime.now object at the moment a key is pressed on the keyboard:

```
DateTime.now start = Console.ReadKey();
```

I've also tried:

```
var start = DateTime.now(Console.ReadKey());
```

That doesn't work either.

I've looked at the documentation for the StopWatch class in C#, but that seems way too advanced for me. I've read the page like 3 times and still don't have clue what it does:
[MS StopWatch class doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8)

I hope someone here can help me out a bit.
best regards,
Jacob Collstrup

Comment: There is a Stopwatch class already in C#
But OK, you can do var now = DateTime.Now; before or after Console.ReadKey()

Comment: Get the value of `DateTime.Now` right after the call to `ReadKey`? `ReadKey()` blocks and returns when the user presses a key.

Comment: What about the existing `Stopwatch` class is confusing exactly? If you look at the methods it's actually very straightforward. You can start, stop, reset, restart, etc. super easily.

Comment: Also, the code you've tried/proposed doesn't really make sense. You need to pay attention to what different methods return and what those return values mean.

Answer (score 3):

For a console app you can get the current date and time by doing `DateTime.Now`. `ReadKey` blocks the flow so you can call `DateTime.Now` it directly after the keypress. Do this twice to get a start and end then you can subtract them to get the duration like this:

```
Console.ReadKey();
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
Console.ReadKey();
DateTime end = DateTime.Now;
var duration = end.Subtract(start);
```

`DateTime.Subtract` will return a `TimeSpan` so you can either print that out or return it upwards if it is going to be in another function.

Looking at your diagram it is suggesting to use `DateTime.Now.Ticks`, there doesn't seem to be much advantage to this, as this will be a `long` and can't use `DateTime.Subtract` on this (obviously you could just still do `end - start`). If needed to return the duration in ticks I would recommend doing the same as I said above however when I use the `duration` variable I would do `duration.Ticks`.

If you do store the `start` and `end` as ticks (`long`) instead then you convert it into a `TimeSpan` then you'll need to do this:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(end - start);
```

Answer (score 2):

What you want is something like this:

```
Console.ReadKey();
DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
```

The call to `Console.ReadKey()` will block until a key has been pressed.  Once that line has returned then you get the current time.

Same for the stop time.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the value of `DateTime.Now` right after the call to `ReadKey()`:

```
Console.ReadKey();
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine("Key was pressed at " + now.ToString());
```

This should work just fine because `ReadKey()` blocks and returns when the user presses a key.